# Cannot create date picker dialog

Tags: java, android

I was using a class inside my activity in order to create a datepicker dialog and it was working until i migrated to android studio.
Here is the class:

```
class StartDatePicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // year, month, day από το onCreate
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Add_Expense.this, this, year, month, day);
        //DatePickerDialog(Context context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth);
        return dialog;

    }
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month,``
            int day) {
        processDate(year, month, day);

    }
    private void processDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        int day_ofWeeks = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        showDate(year, month, day, day_ofWeeks);
    }
}


        public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new StartDatePicker();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "start_date_picker");
}
```

The class StartDatePicker now raises an error: This fragment class should be public. After I declare it as public it raises another error: This fragment inner class should be static.
I don't want to declare it as static because private void showDate(int year, int month, int day, int day_ofWeek) will not work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Apurva How's your answer related to this question? Did you read about the errors OP is facing?

Comment: It seems like Apurva's answer is working properly for the moment...

Comment: That answer has nothing to do with the `public` or `static` class errors you're getting. It just promotes to switch to another style of popping the dialog, dropping the issue altogether. And while that may work out for you, it renders this question useless for future reference.

Comment: where is showDate() defined?

Comment: @nPn  showDatePickerDialog is called via xml from button.

Comment: @Ravi Thapliyal you are right. I think it demands it to be static because it says the class won't run if onResume function runs.

Comment: @Remend I was asking about showDate() which you said is private and was the issue when you made the outer class public and inner class static

Comment: @nPn Oh it is outside from class just below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a cleaner way to do this but, if you make StartDatePick public and static then you could do this:

in StartDatePicker create a field to hold a reference to your outer class

```
OuterClassType  mDateShower;
```

and create a setter for that field.

```
public void setDateShower(OuterClassType dateShower) {
    mDateShower = dateShower;
}
```

then replace your call to `showDate(....);` with `mDateShower.showDate(...);`

finally set the dateShower

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new StartDatePicker();
    newFragment.setDateShower(this);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "start_date_picker");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please tell me the cleaner way? I also find it kind of bad code, so I used Apurva's recommendation.

Comment: `btn_dt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(Add_Expense.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                                processDate(year, month, day);
                            }
                        }, year, month, day);
                dpd.show();
            }
        });`
Is that better?
Thanks.

Comment: Its not really "bad" code.  "cleaner" would have been to use an interface like  "DateShower" rather than the concrete OuterClassType (which OuterClassType would have implemented by providing showDate().)  It is however fair to ask how this worked prior to your migration to Android Studio.